# Нет перевода текста нового всплывающего окна рядом с кнопкой "Закладки"

Tags: дефект, локализация

Возле значка о закладках появилось новое всплывающее окно. Пока без перевода.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вся функциональность без перевода и закладка, и блок в личном кабинете, и FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

Добавил перевод в traducir

> **Original String:**
> New! Save questions or answers and organize your favorite content.
> **Translate:**
> Новинка! Добавляйте вопросы или ответы в закладки и организуйте ваш любимый контент.

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18499

<strike>**Требуется подтверждение для публикации.**</strike>

**UPDATE:** подтверждено. ожидаем публикации.