# В справке отсутствует перевод по сохранению (Saves) сообщений

Tags: дефект, локализация, справка, закладки

В [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help), вот тут отсутствует перевод по сохранению (Saves) сообщений.

[image]

Comment: Обо всём этом уже есть вопросы: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11065/176217 https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2109/176217 https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12159/176217 Про "saves" только в виде комментария.